# Android design supporting many kinds of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I know there are plenty of materials about my question. But I'm still confused how to design android app to support difference sizes of screen.

Mostly when I design web, I use percent to support different size of screens. But as you know, in android, in order to do that, I have to make UI in realtime using Java code(read width and height and resize all the Views depending on screen size), because with XML, you can't do this. But this seems not right.

I have image files(PNG, JPG), and I arrange these files as ImageView and scaleType as "fitXY" and I set width as DP. I know that "dp" unit will make this element consistently same real size and for this reason people use it for widgets. So I put this image in xxxhdpi screen and when I see in xhdpi screen, image is so huge that the image is cut.

What I want is very simple. I want to arrange View elements as percent to width so that layout is very similar in different screens(different height ratio will be resolved with scroll maybe?). But I don't know how to...???? Not only percent.. I just want to know normal process of generating image files and arranging widgets for different screens...

Should I make many image files for different screen and put these in res/drawable-xxxxx ? If I do this, does android system use different files for different screen automatically? Or, Should I make many layouts for each different screen all the time(this seems stupid..)?

Could anyone guide me please?... I have been looking for this answer more than 1 week. Please...

Comment: Who said that you can adjust UI using only JAVA code? XML layout also does the job.

Comment: I mean, in order to arrange components as percent to different screen size. Please read carefully.. Of course you adjust UI using XML layout.... I'm not stupid..

Comment: You typically use LinearLayout and weightSum then  divide out weights for subviews

Comment: You can arrange them in percentage. `layout_weight` does the job.

Comment: `because with XML, you can't do this` it's wrong. Please google it and get some knowledge.

Comment: So I have to use only LinearLayout to do this.. Thanks cricket_007 and activesince93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create different layout folders and create layouts for standard screen sizes. There is a set of six generalized densities:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

You can create images and layouts for these and use accordingly.Mention that in you manifest also:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />        
</compatible-screens>
```

Refer [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

Comment: You mean so there is no way to make only one layout which support all screen size? so, to support 6 screens, I have to make 120 layouts if I have 20 activity.. this seems not right.. But is this really the only way?

Comment: Try not to specify  any size parameters manually. Always use layout weights and align layouts accordingly.Then the screen space will be used properly to a great extent. If this is not working well, you have to do as i mentioned in answer

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to use LinearLayout more often. I mostly used RelativeLayout and FrameLayout.