# Android app looks weird on phone with different resolution

Tags: android, xml, layout, resolution, screen-size

it's the first time I design an app for android and my problem is that when I test the app on a phone with 5" (480 x 800 resolution) the app looks weird and all the icons interfere with each other. However; when I test this app with a 5" (720 x 1280 resolution) the app looks great. I know how to make a different layout for each screen size but I don't know the relation between screen resolution and layouts since both screens are considered "large"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34012724/4494555

Answer (score 1):

- *xlarge* screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- *large* screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- *normal* screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- *small* screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Create a folder named layout-large and put there your layout for large screen (720x1280) and for the normal screen (480x800) put the layout file in layout folder.

Read more
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

or

[Android design supporting many kinds of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012695/android-design-supporting-many-kinds-of-screen/34012724#34012724)

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple devices you have to create and keep images in different drawable folders. 
You can simply generate drawables of an image using the following site [Android Image Asset generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) . Simply you have to Choose what type of image you want. You can choose color of the image. I use it very often. Its very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is "Relative Layout" , you can use a Relative Layout to satisfy your need.
use Relative position for elements in  Your view.
You can use following attributes:
like toRightof,AlignParent...etc

[click here for more attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)